# Brownian dynamics simulations in confined geometries

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, boundary-conditions, brownian-motion

I am currently trying to implement a 2D Brownian dynamics simulation in confined geometries (corrugated channels, of the form $A\cos(2 \pi x) \ + B\ $ in this case). The concept is to compute the effective diffusion coefficient, which will be less than the bulk (or particle) diffusion coefficient in the presence of low external forces (or absence of forces) - due to the confinement. More information is available in [Thesis](https://opus.bibliothek.uni-augsburg.de/opus4/1198) and [Burada, Schmic and Hanggi 2009](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40485654).

The brownian dynamics difference equations I use are (absence of force along $y$ direction),

$$
x^{t + 1} \ = \ x^t \ + \ Force_x \times \Delta t \ + \ \sqrt{\Delta t} \times \zeta_1
$$

$$
y^{t + 1} \ = \ y^t  \ + \ \sqrt{\Delta t} \times \zeta_2
$$

The effective diffusion coefficient is calculated as,
$$Deffx = \frac{<x^2(t)> \ - \ <x(t)>^2}{t}$$
and similarly along the $y$ direction.

The channel top & bottom walls use reflecting boundary conditions [Burada, Schmic and Hanggi 2009](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40485654). Though these seem to work fine at these walls, I am facing problem with the boundary conditions (absorbing/periodic) at the left & right walls.

**Boundary conditions** 
Periodic boundary condition was implemented such that if the particle exits the domain on one side, it will enter the opposite side (for a fixed domain size of, say $-1.5$ to $+1.5$ as per the code below). However, as per the Figs. [3, 4], the effective diffusion coefficient tends to $0$ at steady state (unrealistic). Similar observation was noticed on using absorbing boundary conditions too. However, if no boundary conditions are used at the left & right walls, and the calculations performed till the particle's final position is reached (as per Figs. [5, 6]), a non-zero effective diffusion coefficient along x direction is observed. Diffusion coefficient along $y$ direction could be $0$ as the particles are homogeneously distributed (as the variance gets $0$).

The code works fine in the absence of any boundaries (free diffusion) and in the presence of straight walls (top & bottom) with no boundaries at the left/right. In the former case, $Deff$ along $x$ and $y$ directions was $1$ ($=$ particle diffusion coefficient), while in the latter case it was $1$ only along $x$ direction. In short, confinement along $x$ direction seems to induce $0$ effective diffusion coefficient on using my absorbing/periodic boundary conditions (which should not be the case).

**Note** : all particles are initially generated from the point $(0, 0)$ (delta proability distribution).

Any advice regarding the implementation of the suitable boundary conditions in this problem or a mistake in my approach (and the code) would be highly appreciated.

**MATLAB code**

```
clc; clear;

% Simulation parameters
NTRA = 10e3; NTIME = 5000; NHIST = 5; DT = 0.01;
XMIN = -1.5; DX = 0.01; XMAX = +1.5;
YMIN = -1.; DY = 0.01; YMAX = 1.;
Xedges = XMIN:DX:XMAX;
Yedges = YMIN:DY:YMAX;
Xcenters = XMIN+DX/2:DX:XMAX-DX/2;
Ycenters = YMIN+DX/2:DY:YMAX-DX/2;

% Top & Bottom wall parameters
% wall offset
amp = (5/2/pi);
% wall amplitude
off = (5.02/2/pi);  

syms B_u(t) B_d(t)
% top wall variation
B_u(t) = amp*cos(2*t*pi) + off;                                             
% bottom wall variation
B_d(t) = -B_u(t);                                                           

% Force along x-direction
fx_mag = [0];
%fx = fx_mag*ones(NTRA, 1);                                                      

lin_t = 0:DT:NTIME*DT; 
lin_x = Xedges;

% Generation of initial NTRA trajectories
x = zeros(NTRA, NTIME);
y = zeros(NTRA, NTIME);
%y = random('Uniform', double(B_d(0)), double(B_u(0)), [NTRA, NTIME]);

% Effective diffusion coefficients
Deffx = zeros(NTIME + 1, NHIST);
Deffy = zeros(NTIME + 1, NHIST);
Var_x = zeros(NTIME + 1, NHIST);
Var_y = zeros(NTIME + 1, NHIST);

% for the absorbing boundary conditions into account, removing these particles away
AbsParts = false(NTRA,1); 

% Mobility coefficients
Mobx = zeros(NTIME + 1, NHIST);
Moby = zeros(NTIME + 1, NHIST);

for i = 1:size(fx_mag,2)
    fx = fx_mag(i)*ones(NTRA, 1);

% Repeat trajectories NHIST times
for k = 1:NHIST
k
    % Iterate across time until steady state (NTIME)
    tic
    for j = 1:NTIME

        % Difference equation
        x(:, j + 1) = x(:, j) + fx*DT + sqrt(DT)*randn(NTRA, 1);
        y(:, j + 1) = y(:, j) + sqrt(DT)*randn(NTRA, 1);

        % Reflective boundary conditions at top/bottom walls
        % if x(j+1) lies outside the domain --> reset to x(j) [Burada's thesis, 2008]        
        BU = double(amp.*cos(2*x(:, j + 1)*pi) + off*ones(NTRA, 1)) - abs(y(:, j + 1));
        %BCs - straight wall
%         BU = amp*ones(NTRA, 1) - abs(y(:, j + 1));

        % returns logical TRUE if particle is outside
        out = BU < 0;        
        % indices of brownian particles lying outside 
        out_ind = find(out);
        x(out_ind, j + 1) = x(out_ind, j);
        y(out_ind, j + 1) = y(out_ind, j);

        % Absorbing BCs --> letting the particles escape out of the wall
%         ind_out = (x(:,j) > XMAX) | (x(:,j) < XMIN);
%         AbsParts = or(AbsParts, ind_out); % those particles which have escaped

        %left/right walls
        R = x(:, j + 1) > XMAX;
        L = x(:, j + 1) < XMIN;
        % returns logical TRUE if particle is outside the left/right walls
        periodR = R > 0; 
        periodL = L > 0;        
        % indices of brownian particles lying outside
        periodR_ind = find(periodR);
        periodL_ind = find(periodL);
        % periodic bcs
        x(periodR_ind, j + 1) =  x(periodR_ind, j + 1) - 2*XMAX; 
        x(periodL_ind, j + 1) = x(periodL_ind, j + 1) + 2*XMAX; 
        % sticky absorbing bcs
%         x(periodL_ind, j + 1) = XMIN;
%         x(periodR_ind, j + 1) = XMAX;
%         y(periodL_ind, j + 1) = 0;
%         y(periodR_ind, j + 1) = 0;

        % calculation of effective diffusion coefficients & mobility currents [Burada, Schmid and Hanggi 2009]
        Deffx(j+1, k) = var(x(:, j + 1))/(j*DT); % denominator 2 should be absent
        Var_x(j+1, k) = var(x(:, j + 1));
        Deffy(j+1, k) = var(y(:, j + 1))/(j*DT); 
        Var_y(j+1, k) = var(y(:, j + 1));
        Mobx(j+1, k) = mean(x(:, j + 1))/((j)*DT);
        Moby(j+1, k) = mean(y(:, j + 1))/((j)*DT);        

        % Diffusion coefficient for nonadsorbed particles (to be used in absorbing bcs only)
%         Deffx2(j+1, k) = var(x(not(AbsParts), j + 1))/(2*(j + 1)*DT);
%         Deffy2(j+1, k) = var(y(not(AbsParts), j + 1))/(2*(j + 1)*DT);
%         Mobx2(j+1, k) = mean(x(not(AbsParts), j + 1))/((j + 1)*DT);
%         Moby2(j+1, k) = mean(y(not(AbsParts), j + 1))/((j + 1)*DT);

    end

    % calculation of probability densities by collecting NHIST histograms 
    px(k, :) = histc(x(:, j + 1), Xedges)/(DX*NTRA);
    py(k, :) = histc(y(:, j + 1), Xedges)/(DY*NTRA);

end
toc

    % avg diffusion coefficients and mobility currents
    Deffx_avg = mean(Deffx, 2);
    Deffy_avg = mean(Deffy, 2);
    Varx_avg = mean(Var_x, 2);
    Vary_avg = mean(Var_y, 2);

    mob_x = mean(Mobx, 2);
    mob_y = mean(Moby, 2);
%     P_all{i} = px;

end

% Post-processing
% Plot of simulation results and initial condition
FName=strcat('_',num2str(NTRA),'Particles_',num2str(NTIME),'x',num2str(DT),'Steps_Geom',num2str(amp),'x',num2str(off),'_f=',num2str(fx));
steps = NTIME;
Times=[ 1                      %Initial Distribution
        ceil(steps*0.01) + 1   %After 1% of the time  
        ceil(steps*0.1)        %After 10% of the time...
        ceil(steps*0.25)
        ceil(steps*0.50)
        floor(steps*1)];

set(groot,'defaultAxesTickLabelInterpreter','latex');      

% Plot of initial particle positions
figure('Position', [10 10 1500 800])
Tname = title(strcat('NTRA = ', num2str(NTRA),', NTIME = ', num2str(NTIME), ...
        'NHIST = ', num2str(NHIST),', DT = ',num2str(DT), ...
        'Force = ', num2str(fx_mag)));
%         'Force = ', num2str(fx_mag), ', y-BC: cos; x-BC: none'));
set(Tname, 'interpreter', 'latex');        
subplot(3,2,1)
Tname = title('t = 0');
yname = ylabel('Y direction');
xname = xlabel('X direction');
set([Tname, xname, yname], 'interpreter', 'latex');
hold on
plot(lin_x, B_u(lin_x),'black');
plot(lin_x, B_d(lin_x),'black');
plot(x(:, 1),y(:, 1),'.','DisplayName',strcat('t = ',num2str(1*DT)));
box on
grid on
hold off

% Plot of effective diffusion coefficients
subplot(3, 2,[2,4])
Tname = title('Effective Diffusion coefficients');
set(Tname, 'interpreter', 'latex');
hold on
% plot(lin_t, mean(Deffx'), '-');
% plot(lin_t, mean(Deffy'), '-');
plot(lin_t, Deffx_avg, '-');
plot(lin_t, Deffy_avg, '-');
%plot(lin_t, Deffx2(:, NHIST), '--')
%plot(lin_t, Deffy2(:, NHIST), '--')
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on')
lname = legend('Eff. diffusion x', 'Eff. diffusion y');
yname = ylabel('Eff. diffusion coefficients');
xname = xlabel('Time');
set([lname, yname, xname], 'interpreter', 'latex');
axis([0 NTIME*DT 0 1.2]);
grid on
box on
% dim = [0.7 0.51 0.3 0.3];
% str = {strcat('NTRA=',num2str(NTRA),', NTIME=',num2str(NTIME)),
%         strcat('NHIST=',num2str(NHIST),', DT=',num2str(DT)),
%         strcat('f=',num2str(fx_mag),', y-BC: cos; x-BC: none')};
% annotation('textbox', dim, 'String', str, 'FitBoxToText', 'on');
hold off

% Plot of Variance distributions
subplot(3,2,6)
Tname = title('Variance');
yname = ylabel('Variance');
xname = xlabel('Time');
set([Tname, xname, yname], 'interpreter', 'latex');
hold on
% plot(lin_t, mean(Var_x'), '-')
% plot(lin_t, mean(Var_y'), '-')
plot(lin_t, Varx_avg, '-')
plot(lin_t, Vary_avg, '-')
set(gca, 'XMinorTick', 'on', 'YMinorTick', 'on')
lname = legend('Variance x', 'Variance y');
set(lname, 'interpreter', 'latex');
axis([0 NTIME*DT 0 inf])
grid on
box on
hold off

% Plot of steady state particle positions
subplot(3,2,3)
hold on
Tname = title(strcat('t = ', num2str(DT*NTIME),' (steady state)'));
yname = ylabel('Y direction');
xname = xlabel('X direction');
set([Tname, xname, yname], 'interpreter', 'latex');
plot(lin_x, B_u(lin_x), 'black');
plot(lin_x, B_d(lin_x), 'black'); 
plot(x((AbsParts),NTIME), y((AbsParts),NTIME),'.','DisplayName', strcat('t = ', num2str(NTIME*DT)));
plot(x(not(AbsParts),NTIME), y(not(AbsParts),NTIME), '.r', 'DisplayName', strcat('t = ',num2str(NTIME*DT)));
grid on
box on
hold off

% Plot of steady state prob distributions
subplot(3,2,5)
hold on
Tname = title('Steady state probability distributions');
yname = ylabel('Probability');
xname = xlabel('X direction');
set([Tname, xname, yname], 'interpreter', 'latex');
plot([Xcenters NaN], mean(px), 'Color', [  0    0.4470    0.7410]);
% errorbar([Xcenters NaN], mean(px), std(px)/sqrt(NHIST), 'LineStyle', 'none','Color', [  0    0.4470    0.7410]);
grid on
box on
hold off;


% figure
% hold on
% for i=1:size(fx_mag,2)
%     plot([Xcenters NaN], mean(P_all{i}),'DisplayName',strcat('f=',num2str(fx_mag(i))));
% axis([-0.5 0.5 0 inf])
% end
% legend('show','location','NorthWest')
% hold off
```

*Force = 0, Periodic bcs (left/right)*
[image: F = 0, periodic bcs]

*Force = 3, Periodic bcs (left/right)*
[image: F = 3, periodic bcs]

*Force = 0, No bcs (left/right)*
[image: F = 0, no bcs]

*Force = 3, No bcs (left/right)*
[image: F = 3, no bcs]

Comment: For the Figs. 2, 4, the x-symmetry was broken due to the force_x acting along that direction. I don't find any x-symmetry broken in Figs. 1, 3 (when no forces are acting). Yes, _D_ is computed from the actual position of the particles, and I don't **reset it to any position after they cross the border**. I have now added some edits in my post (concerning the Fig. description).

Comment: I don't find any broken x-symmetry in Figs. 1, 3. x-Asymmetry will be present in Figs. 2, 4 as force is acting along x-direction. Yes, I compute _D_ with the actual particle's position, and **don't reset it back to (-0.5, 0.5) once the border is crossed**. I just added some edits in my post now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about reviewing code and not physics.

Comment: Contrary to your comments, it seems to me from a quick look that you *are* computing the diffusion coefficient from positions which have had periodic boundary conditions applied. This would be incorrect, you need to calculate the diffusion coefficient from uncorrected versions of the positions. Having said that, I agree with @KyleKanos that this is not the appropriate place to ask for people to look closely at your code, and so I won't be doing that in detail.

Comment: @LonelyProf, Thank you for pointing this out clearly. I now calculate the diffusion coefficient along x on the uncorrected positions, and apply the periodic boundary conditions at the end of the simulation. Now, this seems to match with the expected results. Additionally, do you happen to know how to proceed for the calculation of diffusion coefficient along y direction, where reflective bcs are used? Calculating the diffusion coefficient before applying the reflective bcs doesn't seem to much change the results (leading to deffy = 0 same as earlier).

Comment: In the $y$ direction you just have confined 1D diffusion. The confinement does not change the diffusion coefficient, it just limits the mean squared displacement at long times. You can solve this problem without doing a simulation, it is a standard exercise in Fourier series solution of a partial differential equation, with appropriate boundary conditions. I advise that you search online, or in text books, because it should be quite informative.

Comment: @LonelyProf, if the confinement along the y-direction does not change the deffy, then shouldn't it be the same as that in the case of free diffusion (along y) in the absence of boundaries (yielding deffy = particle/bulk diffusion coefficient, 1 in this case) ?

Comment: The way you define the effective diffusion coefficient will give you zero (at long times), because you simply divide the mean-square displacement by the time. This is true for any confined system. Consequently, I don't think that this $D_{\text{eff}}=0$ is particularly informative. I don't think that I have any more to add; extended discussion in the comments is generally discouraged.

Comment: @KyleKanos I disagree on your judgement of off-topics for this question. The "computational-physics" tag was indicated. Although debugging of code is not considered as acceptable, it is allowed to ask questions on i) numerical methods (not using p.b.c for diffusion coefficient *is* part of the algorithm); ii) limitations (D cannot be extracted from mean square displacements for spatially limited motion). Moreover, including a code or a piece of code helps a lot to understand better problems with the algorithm, as the answers have clearly shown.

Comment: @GiorgioP OP asked us to look at his code and critique it, but we don't do code review here. If he wanted to ask about applying certain BCs in the simulation or about calculating the diffusion coeff, those could be on topic (though I imagine someone would suggest [scicomp.se]). But the code review asked is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @KyleKanos  The main request by the OP was "advice regarding the implementation of the suitable boundary conditions in this problem or a mistake in my approach". The code was in parenthesis. I see a perfectly admissible question about computational physics, equivalent to may other admissible questions on different physics sub-topics. I acknowledge that you have a different opinion, but I remain with the mine.

Comment: @GiorgioP The key word in that request being *implementation*. Not "what kind of boundary conditions should I use" but"how correctly have I written it?" The answer given doesn't even talk about suitability of the BCs but does a review of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your definition of diffusion is incompatible with periodic B.C.'s in x. When you reset the position of particles across the boundary, as in:

> x(periodR_ind, j + 1) =  x(periodR_ind, j + 1) - 2*XMAX;

you limit the spread of the particles. Once the particles diffuse between the boundaries the ensemble averages will no longer change. This should be expected. Your calculation of diffusion is based on an ensemble of 'single-particles', but periodic B.C.'s have a periodic array of particles. Once the particles start crossing the boundary the statistics change.

Of course, in  a real fluid there are many particles which usually already distributed in space. So how can you see Brownian motion in that case? If you can track particles then you look at their velocities (or equivalently you can plot the total distance traveled by each particle...i.e. getting rid of periodic B.C.'s). This can be expressed by looking at the velocity auto-corrrelation function $v(t_1)v(t_2-t_1)$.

Also note that Brownian motion usually refers to the case where there is a frictional force slowing the particles down.

Comment: Thanks. After seeing your answer, along with @LonelyProf's comment, I now apply the periodic boundary conditions at the end of my simulation (mapping all particles into a single periodic domain). Though, this might sound easier along x-direction (due to the periodic property - rearranging the particles), do you have any suggestion for the diffusion coefficient computation along y-direction (reflective boundary conditions applied here)? Unfortunately, I am not aware about the procedure with the velocity auto-correlation? In my simplified case, I have assumed the friction coefficient to be 1.

Comment: Although Brownian motion often refers to the Langevin equation (with velocities), [Brownian dynamics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_dynamics) frequently refers to the overdamped version, in which the velocities do not appear. This equation (given at the bottom of that Wikipedia page) is valid on a timescale longer than the velocity correlation time. This is what the OP is doing. So an approach based on the velocity autocorrelation function would not be appropriate here.

Comment: @GreenApples: please don't answer code review questions. They are explicitly off-topic on this site and giving them an answer indicates that such answers are on topic, which isn't true.